# How can I insert every 10th row in an array list to?

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, eclipse

how can I insert every 10th row in an array list to ?
This is my Code:

```
 openDB();
     Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();
     List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(c.getCount());

     while (c.moveToNext()) {        
         valueList.add(c.getInt(1));

     }
     c.close();
     closeDB();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 openDB();
     Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();
     List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(c.getCount());

     List<Integer> tenthRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     counter = 0;
     while (c.moveToNext()) {  
         Integer value = c.getInt(1);      
         valueList.add(value );
         counter++;
         if(counter == 10) {
             tenthRows.add(value)
             counter = 0;
         }
     }
     c.close();
     closeDB();
```